# set cell background dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, netbeans-8

```
    function generate_table(maze, rowNum, colNum, imgsrc) {
    var tb = document.getElementById("MyMaze");
    for(i = 0;i < rowNum;i++){
        var row = tb.insertRow(i);
        for(j = 0;j < colNum; j++){
            var cell = row.insertCell(j);
            if(maze[i * rowNum + j] === '1'){
                cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            } else if(maze[i * rowNum + j] === '#'){
                cell.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            }else if(maze[i * rowNum + j] === '*'){
                cell.style.backgroundColor = 'url(' + imgsrc + ')';
            }else if(maze[i * rowNum + j] === '0'){
                cell.style.backgroundColor = "#e0e0eb";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

After a debug I checked the path (imgsrc is good it is "images/back.jpg"), however the code does not work!
how can I set the background correctly?

Comment: i changed it to:     cell.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgsrc + ')';

Comment: the chrome says: MenuServlet:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: imgSrc is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`backgroundImage`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp)** property when the background is an image.

```
cell.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + imgsrc + '")';
```

Comment: @EstiQueroub can you try `'url("' + imgsrc + '")'`?

Comment: not working.. i am trying to put the explicit url to check if there is a problem with the path

Comment: i have a problem when i want to pass the path of the image .. do you know how to do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

use only background property to add an image with url

```
cell.style.background = "url('+imgsrc+')";
```